# Monitor Progress For Long Insert/Update Queries

Tags: jquery, sql-server-2008, progress-bar, asp.net-4.0, epplus

I have a web application that allows a user to upload an Excel spreadsheet to insert ~250,000 records at a time into a database. I'd like to have a progress bar that shows the user how far along the process is.

Here's my basic plan

1. Upload a spreadsheet
2. Write total `ExcelRow Count` to `TempTable`
3. Loop through cells in each row to build sql and execute query (for each row)
4. Client makes ajax call every 3 seconds to get `Count(*) From TempTable Group By ExcelRowID`
5. Update progress bar until 100%

Is there a better way of doing this? Is there anything I should watch out for? Will this work?

I'm using ASP.Net 4.0, SQL Server 2008 R2 Express, EPPlus 3.0, and jQuery 1.7.1

Comment: Isn't it going to be MUCH slower by executing a query for each row? How about batching and instead keep track on of how many batches are done and how many are left?

Comment: @RogerLindsjö so maybe do it in batches of 10,000 rows, but still keep the same general structure?

Comment: I think it is better if your "server side" keeps track of the update progress rather than querying the db. So, basically with the upload include a id that you can the query the progress about with ajax. For each batch update the status for the id (that ajax queries). This would also allow you to execute several of these uploads in parallel.

Comment: @RogerLindsjö so I'd keep it in a session variable or something and have the update process check on that variable every few seconds?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up just approximating the time and making a very elaborate progressbar to entertain the user.